How does the inner element of the ScrollView receive the full touchEvents sequence as it slides?
I have a ScrollView with a lot of items - A,B,C... The OnTouchListener is set for all items to listen for ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE, and ACTION_UP event sequences. For example, when I swipe up and down while holding A, A only receives the ACTION_DOWN touchEvent, and subsequent touchEvents are captured by ScrollView. How do I set it up so that A can receive the full sequence of touchEvents while ScrollView is still sliding?

